# Any way to find other annotations on methods that are annotated with EventListeners using the resulting ApplicationListener returned from the context?

Tags: spring

It looks like the ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter hides the method it is annotated for making it impossible to look if that method potentially contains other Annotations.  There is some other way around this?

if i have an event listener like this

```
@EventListener
@SomeOtherAnnotation
public void onSomeEvent(SomeEvent e) {
    ...
}
```

and a custom event multicaster

```
public class CustomEventMulticaster extends SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster {

    public <T extends ApplicationEvent> void trigger(final T event,
        Function<ApplicationListener<T>, Boolean> allowListener) {
        ...
    }

}
```

i'd like to do something like trigger only if some annotation exists

```
customEventMulticaster.trigger(someEvent, (listener) -> {
    return listener.getClass().getAnnotation(SomeOtherAnnotation.class) == null;
})
```

Comment: Can you show us actual code ?

Comment: updated my original comment with code

Comment: *listener.getClass().getAnnotation(SomeOtherAnnotation.class)* this gives you annotation on class, while you are annotating on method.

Comment: Yes that works on a listener is a class using the old style of implementing ApplicationListener<T>.  But since spring 4.2 using the @EventAnnotation, when returning the listener you get an adapter class ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter that hides the details of the method being annotation

Comment: Unless you find a way how to get that method, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a hacky solution - just as case study - but please don't go that way.

Since your application `listener` is in fact `ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter` you can use reflection to get `method` or `targetMethod` from that class. From there you can get method annotations.

More or less (not checked, pure notepad here)

```
customEventMulticaster.trigger(someEvent, (listener) -> {
    Field f=((ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter)listener).getDeclaredField("method"); // or 'targetMethod' - consult ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter to get the difference
    f.setAccessible(true);
    Method m=f.get(listener); // cast again if required
    anno=m.getAnnotation(yourAnno); // here you can access annotation
    return anno == null;
})
```

To make this at least to pretend ot be safe, add nullchecks and check if listener is indeed castable to `ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter`

Comment: thanks I thought about reflection, but I agree i really don't want to go down that path.  It sucks that the adapter puts a lot of the source objects as private.  I can't even extend it for access.